# virtual machine Audio Device Rename

Tags: azure, audio, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to rename my audio device name. but it doesn't do anything when I rename it. it just simply close the setting. My setting for RDP is Local Resource-->play on this computer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to rename the audio device name on the VM as you are using remote audio driver from Microsoft to output the sound to your local machine . The driver name is bydefault remote audio.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to rename audio device name?

Comment: Hello @AhmedAli, I couldn't find any other way to change it , I tried from settings , Control panel and device manager after i change the name it gets reversed back to remote audio. So, i don't think its possible to do that